# Windows Service : How to register with Castle to inject 2 Quartz job into the service class

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, quartz.net

I want to create 2 quartz jobs with different triggers and schedule them during (Windows) Service start. How should I register 'MyService' so that it is gets the job instances?

```
public class MyService: IService
{
  private IJobDetail job1, job2;
  ....
  public MyService(IJobDetail job1, IJobDetail job2) { }

  public void Start() 
  {
    _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, TriggerBuilder.Create()... );
    _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job2, TriggerBuilder.Create()... );
  }
 }
```

Now, my WindsorInstaller looks like this:

```
 container.Register(Component.For<IJob>()
                              .ImplementedBy<Job1>()
                              .Named("Job1"));

 container.Register(Component.For<IJob>()
                              .ImplementedBy<Job2>()
                              .Named("Job2"));

 container.Register(Component.For<IJobDetail>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
            {
                var job = container.Resolve<IJob>("Job1");
                return JobBuilder.Create(job.GetType())...
            })
 container.Register(Component.For<IJobDetail>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
            {
                var job = container.Resolve<IJob>("Job2");
                return JobBuilder.Create(job.GetType())...
            })

 container.Register(Component.For<IService>()
                             .ImplementedBy<MyService>());
```

I am also implementing IJobFactory which would instantiate the job using

```
   container.Resolve<bundle.JobDetail.JobType>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are needing to this via DI? You may be better off having Quartz read your scheduler, job, and triggers dynamically from its built in XML file reader. It will take care of adding your jobs, attaching them to triggers, etc. Here is some code I wrote as an example: https://github.com/cknightdevelopment/CodeIn60Seconds/tree/master/DotNet/QuartzWithXmlConfiguration

Comment: A.  Don't reinvent the wheel ( http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/16/install-quartz.net-as-a-windows-service-and-test-installation.aspx )   B.  You can add your jobs via .xml configuration .. aka, a "version" of DI.  If you're concrete IJobs need DI/Ioc, that's one thing...but trying to generically wire up DI is not very fruitful.